# Отправка отформатированного сообщения

Tags: php

Привет! Не могу разобраться как без дополнительных классов и фреймворков с помощью функции mail() отправить отформатированное письмо - c тэгами, картинками и т.д... Возможно ли это в принципе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглится на [раз](http://www.php.su/functions/?mail)

```
    /* получатели */
    $to = "Mary <mary@example.com>" . ", "; //обратите внимание на запятую
    $to .= "Kelly <kelly@example.com>";

    /* тема/subject */
    $subject = "Birthday Reminders for August";

    /* сообщение */
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>3rd</td>
            <td>August</td>
            <td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sally</td>
            <td>17th</td>
            <td>August</td>
            <td>1973</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    /* Для отправки HTML-почты вы можете установить шапку Content-type. */
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    /* дополнительные шапки */
    $headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";

    /* и теперь отправим из */
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Странно, что я  был на этой странице, но у меня ничего не получилось... Сейчас тупо скопировал ваш ответ, вставил себе и, о чудо! - заработало!

Comment: @ua6xh, важно было указание именно MIME-version